# Run MPI on two hosts

Tags: mpi

I am a beginner in MPI programming and I want to program in parallel with two separate computers. I want to send an array to another computer. I saw the send() function which send the address of the array, but we have two separate computer that don't have "shared memory." So how can I use the send function in MPI to send an array to "another computer"?

Answer (score 1):

I think you have a fundamental misunderstanding of what MPI is. It's not necessarily a way to use shared memory to send data between two processes (though it can be used for that). At it's core, it's a way of sending data from one process to another, whether that process is on the same machine or not. When you use the `MPI_SEND` function, you're not sending the address of the data from one process to another, you're giving the address of the data to the MPI library which is then sending a copy of that data to another process which receives it by calling `MPI_RECV`.

I would highly suggest finding a good tutorial for learning some of the MPI basics. A quick search in your favorite search engine will help, but I can seed the pot if you like.

1. A good reference site is [Deino MPI](http://mpi.deino.net). This won't necessarily teach you about MPI as a whole, but it's a great reference if you need to see an example for each function in MPI.
2. [This](http://www.mcs.anl.gov/research/projects/mpi/learning.html) site has links to lots of MPI tutorials. They're a little dated at this point, but they are still valid, especially for the MPI basics.
3. There are a couple of good books, [Using MPI](http://mitpress.mit.edu/books/using-mpi) and [Using MPI - 2nd Edition](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0262571323) that are very popular with people learning MPI.

I'm sure there's more out there, but this should get you started.

Comment: thank you very much for your answer, I got it, but I have another fundamental question?I don't know really how should I run my program on 2 or 3 host,I mean I don't know the instructions of that,I googled a lot for it.but I couldn't find some useful link,could you suggest me a new tutorial about **running my program on multiple pcs**

Comment: All of the tutorials I mentioned about will talk about all of that. You will need to spend some time with them to understand what MPI actually is and how to use it.